# CSS3 e HTML5 shape-outside

Tags: html, css

Como fazer igual imagem em baixo? Com HTML e CSS

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma solução pra fazer isso seria utilizando Clip-path

[como nesse exemplo](http://codepen.io/pen/), tem até o um [site que gerá automática mente](http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) porém não tem suporte pra todos os browsers

Mas a melhor solução é do [Joseph Fusco](http://angled-edges.josephfus.co/) que coloca um svg a a borda que ele quer desenhada. Essa tem suporte pra todos os browsers

no exemplo que vc colocou dá pra fazer da seguinte forma

- criaria um svg com o desenho do corte em cor branca
- colocaria dentro do css esse svg em base64 com `after`

Se achar difícil demais é pegue a imagem fateada em png com essa parte cortada transparente